Unexpected token 'export' with React 17
I am using Jest with React to write unit test cases for my project with the following specs. When I run yarn test (Jest --coverage). It gives me below error.
Error: Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token.....

    Details:

    <root dir>/node_modules/cheerio/dist/browser/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){export { contains, merge } from './static.js';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      3 | import { configure } from 'enzyme';
      4 |
    > 5 | global.ResizeObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        |                                                  ^
      6 |     observe: jest.fn(),
      7 |     unobserve: jest.fn(),
      8 |     disconnect: jest.fn(),

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/Utils.js:93:16)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:33:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/enzyme/build/index.js:3:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17/build/ReactSeventeenAdapter.js:11:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17/build/index.js:3:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (test/setup.js:5:50)

My Jest and Babel versions respectively are 29.7.0 and 7.24.0.
Here is my Jest.config.js file.
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ["./test/setup.js"],
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^.+\\.(less|css)$": "babel-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/?!(cheerio|jest-runtime|enzyme|@wojtekmaj)"
  ],
  testTimeout: 30000,
};

Here is my setup.js file:
import 'raf/polyfill';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';

global.ResizeObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
}))

global.CSS = {
    escape: (str) => str,
};

configure({
    adapter: new Adapter(),
});

I tried multiple online solutions tweaking the regexp for transformIgnorePattern field but no luck. Please suggest on the right regexp to use here to get rid of this error or anything else that would be needed.

I've encountered similar errors before, so here are my thoughts:
That's good that you have the ResizeObserver mocked and it's in your setupFiles (that's often forgotten to add it there). But you can try the following:

I'd update the regex to something like this: node_modules\/(?!(${moduleNames.join('|')})\/) and then pass in module names. Note how this regex escapes the first fwd/slash, whereas yours doesnt yet.

const modulesToMap = (modules) => `node_modules\/(?!(${modules.join('|')})\/)`;

const modules = ['cheerio','jest-runtime','enzyme','@wojtekmaj'];

So your transformIgnorePatterns would be:
module.exports = {
...
  transformIgnorePatterns: [modulesToMap(modules)],
}


Try adding a window definition to your mock file as well?  I have something similar mocked for Jest, but for IntersectionObserver. But as you can see below, my file contains both window and global definitions. It doenst matter the exact syntax (e.g., using a class, like I've done versus, not), but try defining both window and global and see if Jest is happier with that

// src/mocks/intersectionObserverMock.js
// Mock IntersectionObserver
class IntersectionObserver {
  observe = jest.fn();
  disconnect = jest.fn();
  unobserve = jest.fn();
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'IntersectionObserver', {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: IntersectionObserver,
});

Object.defineProperty(global, 'IntersectionObserver', {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  value: IntersectionObserver,
});


Lastly, in your jest.config.js (make sure that's a lowercase "J" btw), perhaps try tweaking the import syntax for you mock file? So rather than ./setup.js my setupFiles in in jest.config.js looks like this:

setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/test/mocks/localStorage.mock.js', '<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/intersectionObserverMock.js'],


Hey There! Thanks for responding. I have tried this approach of clubbing all the node module names and adding it to transformIgnorePattern via loop and as a standalone regexp but it still throws the same error. Unfortunately, I don't think this has anything to do with the IntersectionObserverMock functions. I was looking at a right regexp to use here or a wildcard regexp that could pass through my test cases. "node_modules/(?!(cheerio|jest-runtime|enzyme|@wojtekmaj)/)" doesn't work.
